# bitácora de un paquete SSIS

Tags: ssis

Quiero saber cual es la tabla donde se guarda la tabla en SQL Server donde se guarda el log de integration services, hasta donde he leído es sysssislog, pero no me aparece nada al dar "select"

Answer (score 0):

Debes activar la opción en el DTS para que genere el histórico en SQL.

En la barra de menú del Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) busca la opción ISSIS y dentro de esta loggin..

En este menú debes configurar el historial a generar para las ejecuciones del DTS.

Si los paquetes se han ejecutado mediante Jobs del SQL Server Agent, entonces puedes mirar de consultar en la tabla  msdb..sysjobhistory.